# How to integrate X-Ray with AWS Lambda function on Command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, x-ray

From the console, it is possible to activate lambda integration with x-ray through the following steps:
From your function in the console > Configuration tab > Advanced dropdown/section > check Enable Active Tracing checkbox > Save.

I couldn't find documentation on how to get the above result in command line so I can easily apply that to all my lambdas instead of going to the individual ones in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following flag via create-function or update-function-configuration.

```
--tracing-config '{ "Mode": "Active" }'
```

From the man page:

```
--tracing-config (structure)

Shorthand Syntax:

   Mode=string

JSON Syntax:

   {
     "Mode": "Active"|"PassThrough"
   }
```

All flags for a given command can be found using

```
aws <service> <command> help
```

I've opened an item with the Lambda team to include it on the X-Ray integration page found here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-x-ray.html

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!